# Get Feature Importances using SKLearn RFECV with Multi-Output Regression Chain, Possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to use RFECV to get a list of the most important features, but trying to use it with RegressionChain on a multi-output regression problem, and running into an issue. I've create a reproducible code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("once")
from sklearn.multioutput import RegressorChain
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators
from sklearn.model_selection import *
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# Create multioutput regression dataset and split
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=100, n_informative=25, n_targets=6)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

# Get a list of all SKLearn regressors, and store in dictionary
estimators = all_estimators(type_filter="regressor")
my_estimators = {name[0]:name[1] for name in estimators}

# Iterate through all estimators
for key, value in my_estimators.items():
    
    # Don't use CV estimators, they hang too often
    if 'cv' in str(key).lower():
        continue

    print(key, value)
    
    # Get the estimator being used currently
    try:
        estimator = my_estimators[key]()
    except:
        continue

    # Use RFECV on the multiouput regression problem
    rfe = RFECV(estimator=RegressorChain(base_estimator=estimator, order=[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5])) # importance_getter=manual_feature_importance_getter(RegressorChain(base_estimator=estimator, order=[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5]), None, 1)
    model = RegressorChain(base_estimator=estimator, order=[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5])
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfe),('m',model)])
    # evaluate model
    cv = KFold(n_splits=2) # n_repeats=2, for Repeated, , random_state=1
    n_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    # report performance
    print('neg_root_mean_squared_error: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(n_scores), std(n_scores)))
```

...which yields the following error:

```
    ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator RegressorChain should
 have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to 
feature selector or call fit before calling transform.
```

I'm getting this error because `RegressionChain` isn't the main estimator, it's just the chain, so it doesn't have `coef_` or `feature_importance_` attributes tied to it, but the base estimator does. So, I need to create my own feature importance getter function, and pass that to the RFECV function, which I'm attempting here:

```
def manual_feature_importance_getter(estimator, transform_func=None, norm_order=1):

    # Get the base estimator from the regression chain
    estimator = estimator.base_estimator

    # This is modified from the SKLearn > Feature Selection > _base.py file
    if hasattr(estimator, 'coef_'):
        getter = attrgetter('coef_')
        importances = getter(estimator)

    elif hasattr(estimator, 'feature_importances_'):
        getter = attrgetter('feature_importances_')
        importances = getter(estimator)

    if transform_func is None:
        return importances
    elif transform_func == "norm":
        if importances.ndim == 1:
            importances = np.abs(importances)
        else:
            importances = np.linalg.norm(importances, axis=0,
                                         ord=norm_order)
    elif transform_func == "square":
        if importances.ndim == 1:
            importances = safe_sqr(importances)
        else:
            importances = safe_sqr(importances).sum(axis=0)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Valid values for `transform_func` are " +
                         "None, 'norm' and 'square'. Those two " +
                         "transformation are only supported now")

    return importances
```

Then I change the RFECV call to this:

```
rfe = RFECV(estimator=RegressorChain(base_estimator=estimator, order=[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5]), importance_getter=manual_feature_importance_getter(RegressorChain(base_estimator=estimator, order=[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5]), None, 1))
```

...but am now getting this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'importances' referenced before assignment
```

...which tells me that the new function's `getter` variable assignments aren't working, because the estimator hasn't been fitted yet, so it doesn't have the `coef_` or `feature_importance_` attributes yet.

Any ideas on how to get this thing running? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

After a bit of research, I discovered that the feature importance getter needs to be "callable", so I changed the `manual_feature_importance_getter` into a callable class, with some print outs to see what it was doing as it went:

```
class manual_feature_importance_getter:

    def __init__ (self, estimator, transform_func=None, norm_order=1):
        self.estimator = estimator
        self.transform_func = transform_func
        self.norm_order = norm_order

    def __call__(self, estimator):

        # Get the base estimator from the regression chain
        estimator = estimator.base_estimator

        # This is modified from the SKLearn > Feature Selection > _base.py file
        if hasattr(estimator, 'coef_'):
            print('yay!')
            getter = attrgetter('coef_')
            importances = getter(estimator)

        elif hasattr(estimator, 'feature_importances_'):
            print('yay!')
            getter = attrgetter('feature_importances_')
            importances = getter(estimator)
        
        else:
            print('DOH!')
            importances = np.zeros(shape=(X_train.shape[1],1))
        

        if self.transform_func is None:
            return importances
        elif self.transform_func == "norm":
            if importances.ndim == 1:
                importances = np.abs(importances)
            else:
                importances = np.linalg.norm(importances, axis=0,
                                             ord=self.norm_order)
        elif self.transform_func == "square":
            if importances.ndim == 1:
                importances = safe_sqr(importances)
            else:
                importances = safe_sqr(importances).sum(axis=0)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Valid values for `self.transform_func` are " +
                             "None, 'norm' and 'square'. Those two " +
                             "transformation are only supported now")

        return importances
```

... which started with the `ARDRegression <class 'sklearn.linear_model._bayes.ARDRegression'>` regressor, but then just outputted this:

```
ARDRegression <class 'sklearn.linear_model._bayes.ARDRegression'>
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
DOH!
```

...which means it's still not getting the feature importances from the estimator's attributes properly as it runs its RFECV. It's like it's not even fitting the regression chain's estimator at all, and is just reverting to the zero importances that I added in there. I made the zero importances array in the hopes that it would just get past that part to start, and that the importances would update throughout the RFECV run, but that doesn't appear to be happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my solution!

What I needed to do in the `manual_feature_importance_getter` was iterate through the FITTED regressions one by one in the chain, and then just sum the importances at the end. So my finished callable class looks like this:

```
class manual_feature_importance_getter:

    def __init__ (self, estimator, transform_func=None, norm_order=1):
        self.estimator = estimator
        self.transform_func = transform_func
        self.norm_order = norm_order

    def __call__(self, estimator):

        # Get the individual base estimators from the fitted regression chain
        all_estimators = estimator.estimators_

        # A place to store the feature importances for each estimator
        all_importances = []

        # Iterate through the fitted estimators
        for i in range(len(all_estimators)):

            estimator = all_estimators[i]

            # This is modified from the SKLearn > Feature Selection > _base.py file
            if hasattr(estimator, 'coef_'):
                print('yay!')
                getter = attrgetter('coef_')
                importances = getter(estimator)

            elif hasattr(estimator, 'feature_importances_'):
                print('yay!')
                getter = attrgetter('feature_importances_')
                importances = getter(estimator)
            
            else:
                print('DOH!')
                importances = np.zeros(shape=(X_train.shape[1],1))

            # Add the importances to the main list
            all_importances.append(importances)

        # Sum all importances together, and put them into an importances numpy array
        importances = np.array([sum(x) for x in zip(*all_importances)])

        if self.transform_func is None:
            return importances
        elif self.transform_func == "norm":
            if importances.ndim == 1:
                importances = np.abs(importances)
            else:
                importances = np.linalg.norm(importances, axis=0,
                                             ord=self.norm_order)
        elif self.transform_func == "square":
            if importances.ndim == 1:
                importances = safe_sqr(importances)
            else:
                importances = safe_sqr(importances).sum(axis=0)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Valid values for `self.transform_func` are " +
                             "None, 'norm' and 'square'. Those two " +
                             "transformation are only supported now")

        return importances
```

Couple that with the rest of the script, and I can now get feature importances for a multioutput regression chain RFECV. Woohoo!

Comment: This can probably be a function again, since the "callable" change seems to have been a red herring.  (Functions _are_ callables.)